# How to exclude all files and directories except one directory, RewriteCond

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to redirect all non-files, non-directories to index.php, so everything that exists is directly accessible - except for one directory (which should also go to index.php)

What I have is:

```
# Files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

# Directories except /orderfiles/*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^/(orderfiles/)* [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule .* index.php [L,QSA]
```

This works for **directories** inside /orderfiles, but a **files** inside of /orderfiles still goes to that file. I tried adding

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^/(orderfiles/)* [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

But this breaks and sends every file to index.php.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're close, you want something like this:

```
# Files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

# Directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# except /orderfiles
RewriteRule !^/?orderfiles index.php [L,QSA]
```

---

> I realized I mistyped what I was trying to do, I meant "but send one directory to index.php" (I edited my question to be more accurate). I do want /orderfiles to be routed to index.php

Then what you have is correct, but you need to change this line:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^/(orderfiles/)* [OR]
```

to:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/orderfiles/ [OR]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response - I realized I mistyped what I was trying to do, I meant "but send one directory to index.php" (I edited my question to be more accurate). I do want /orderfiles to be routed to index.php.

Comment: Thank you! I was still having trouble (it wouldn't work without the parenthesis like you posted), so I changed ^(/orderfiles/)* to ^/new/orderfiles/ ,  I had RewriteBase /new/ above, so I didn't realize I had to include /new/ again. This made it all work. Thanks again.