# Htaccess rule to ignore folder only if it's NOT a specific host

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Need a little guidance for my Apache .htaccess rules. Should be a nice easy one for you wizards :)

Basically the setup is this:

- Root domain is used to access our front site (admin & selling) which uses `www` at all times through our root domain and is loaded from our application.
- We have Wordpress setup on /blog this will always and should only be loaded on `www` subdomain of our main root domain.
- We allow wild card subdomains and custom domains for our users pages so basically anything `*.domain.com` or `usersdomain.com` is routed through Codeigniter to display the correct page for the user.
- We need to let `/blog/` be used for the wildcard domains and subdomains to load a `/blog/` page on the users pages as well so they have their own blog basically. In other words. Any non `www.domain.com` host should bypass the `/blog` Wordpress install and route to our application to load the correct non-wordpress page from the application.

**Right now if you access `usersdomain.com/blog/` or `userssubdomain.domain.com` it loads the Wordpress install, this is not desired behaviour.**

Here is our current htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond $1 !^blog
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

---

Does anyone have any ideas how to achieve the above? Basically need a RewriteRule or Condition which says

> "If request host is not `www.domain.com` then ignore `/blog` directory and
>   send to `index.php`"

#### For Reference

I was looking at this question for ideas but with no luck: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12502885/how-to-exclude-all-files-and-directories-except-one-directory-rewritecond](//stackoverflow.com/questions/12502885/how-to-exclude-all-files-and-directories-except-one-directory-rewritecond)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added the following to the .htaccess in my /blog/ directory to fix this.

```
#rewrite back to root index if not local dev or live main host
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^dev\.local\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* /index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

The draw back is of course that 2 htaccess files have to be read for each request in this category which isn't ideal but it works and it's not a primary function of the application.